# iptables settings open ports

Tags: iptables, port-scanning

**ipables configuration**

Trying to allowing connection to a server from the outside world. Port scanners are reporting the ports are not open. Just after confirmation my iptables are correctly set.

eth0 - Private Lan
tun0 - VPN interface
ppp0 - Mobile broadband connection (no firewall restrictions from ISP)

```
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i tun0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i ppp0 -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i ppp0 -p udp -m multiport --dports 53,1194 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i ppp0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 25,53,80,143,443,587 -j ACCEPT
```

Hoping iptables is the culprit otherwise I'm going to have spend a lot more time on working on this server. Appreciate the assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that is the **entirety** of your firewall ruleset, then I agree that you should have opened up traffic to UDP ports 53 and 1194, and TCP ports 25, 52, 80, 143, 443, and 587.

If you want a little more insight into whether it is your firewall that is the problem, add a last line

```
-A INPUT -j LOG --log-prefix "INPUT DROP: "
```

and watch to see if any log entries appear in the usual place (often `/var/log/messages`, but it will depend on your `rsyslog` setup).

If packets still don't make it through, but nothing is logged, you will have more confidence that something off-server is an issue.  By the way, port scanners aren't the best way to tell if you've opened up a TCP port; try eg `telnet server 443` from a random client.  It's simpler and thus has less ways to fail than a port scanner, and so there is less risk of your drawing false conclusions.

Comment: Thank you for the info. Expedited clarifying if it is a iptables problem. As no drops are being recorded I am going to go back to the ISP and get them to test. The fight for workability continues.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line,

```
-A INPUT -i ppp0 -p tcp  -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Please try posting a bit more detailed answers